# How do I rename an index row in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I see how to rename columns, but I want to rename an index (row name) that I have in a data frame.

I had a table with 350 rows in it, I then added a total to the bottom. I then removed every row except the last row.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|            |     A      |     B     |     C    |
-------------------------------------------------
|     TOTAL  |    1243    |       423 |     23   |
-------------------------------------------------
```

So I have the row called 'Total', and then several columns. I want to rename the word 'Total' to something else.

Is this even possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a dictionary structure with `rename()`, for example,

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

        df = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
        df
Out[1]: 0    1
        1    2
        2    3
        dtype: int64

In [2]: df.rename({1: 3, 2: 'total'})
Out[2]: 0        1
        3        2
        total    3
        dtype: int64
```

Comment: Excellent, worked perfectly! Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Easy as this...

```
df.index.name = 'Name'
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the quick response. I did as you said, but now I have a new row called 'foo' with blank entries in all the columns, and then the 'Total' row has been shifted down with all the data (so I now have two rows of data)?

Comment: Can you update your main question above to show your code please.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. Manel's solution below has worked the trick :)

Comment: no problem. that is okay